# How do I convert my Blackberry contacts to a standard format?

Tags: ldap, migration

I want to migrate from Blackberry (RIP).  How do I convert my contacts to a standard format?

Comment: Wondering, what your source format of your contacts? I'm assuming you were working from a literal BlackBerry backup file? Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 1):

I just got this working so figured I'd document it for posterity.

```
sudo apt-get install barry-util barrybackup-gui barrydesktop
```

Then use the backup utility GUI to make a complete backup of your database.  We'll call it `backup.tar.gz`.

Unfortunately the desktop utility seems to only export one record at a time.

Instead, use the command line:

```
btardump -d 'Address Book' -V backup.tar.gz > address_book.mime
```

That's it.  The `.mime` file should have a bunch of VCards inside.

Comment: Which package has to be installed?

Comment: @thefourtheye Oops.  Thanks for reminding me.  This is actually critical to the ease-of-use of this approach, as other instructions for doing part of this out there want a library that's not in the main repository.